# Sync branches in git

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I'm sure this is a simple one but I haven't been able to find the answer online, even after much Googling.

I have Git installed on my machine, for which I followed the tutorial on the Github site.  Following this made my machine master.  Now, I need to work on a different branch.  So I created a new branch on the site.  Problem: this new branch isn't showing up in the Bash window, and when I try to switch to it, it isn't recognized.  A coworker created his branch and it isn't on my machine either.

How can I synchronize the list of branches on the site with my machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to get other's branch repositories on your local system, make a directory of their name on your system and inside it do

```
$git init 
$git clone <git repo url>
```

you can find the repo url in the github site.

for clarifying your basic git concepts follow this site:

http://gitimmersion.com/

Answer (score 0):

Got it actually, I just needed to do

```
$git fetch --all
```

and then I could switch to it fine.